# How to prevent echoing of escape characters in c

Tags: c, linux, escaping, echo

Basically, I want to scan input using using getchar(), and I want that if the user enters a character like ESC or arrow keys, this should not be echoed on the screen at all, but I still want that input to be proccessed.

Answer (score 0):

See man for ascii(7):

```
Oct   Dec   Hex   Char
...
033   27    1B    ESC (escape)
```

This is the code for escape character.

Answer (score 0):

Something to get you started. Basically you need to turn ECHO off and set the terminal into unbuffered mode. Then you have to filter the ANSI escape sequences. These are ESC (27) followed by [ and a letter. The example below has been tested in OS X, but probably should work in Linux.

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int c,escseen=0,code;
  struct termios t;
  tcgetattr(0, &t);
  t.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO|ICANON);
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &t);


  for(;;)
  {
    c=getchar();
    if(c>=32)
    {
        if(escseen)
            if(c=='[')
            {
                code=getchar();
                /* do something with the esc code */
                continue;
            }

        putchar(c);
        escseen=0;
    }
    else
        if(c==27)
        {
          escseen=1;
        }
  }
}
```